# AngularJS - Id for every option in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I have the following ng-options

```
<select name="campaigns" ng-options="ac.campaignId in campaigns | filter:{category: filterSelectOptions} | orderBy: 'name'">
    <option value="">Choose one</option>
</select>
```

It's working fine, but I want every option to have an Id attribute. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: The purpose of this is to make each option visible for my Java Selenium test. It finds elements by id or name.

Comment: This *feels like* an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  What is the purpose of having an `id` attribute?

Comment: You might be right. I need to make each option available for my Java Selenium test to be clickable either by id or name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this work around, assign string which you are getting from ng-option to option tag id.

`<select name="campaigns" ng-options="ac.campaignId in campaigns | filter:{category: filterSelectOptions} | orderBy: 'name'">
    <option value="" id={{ac.campaignId}}>Choose one</option>
</select>`

Comment: This doesn't work. It only assigns an id attribute to the default option. I need an id attribute on each generated option from the ng-options unfortunately.

Comment: May i know for what reason you want id to the options?

Answer (score 0):

Try this work. I Worked With Fine. Use ng-model to Get Key Value. And Use Value = -1 or Non Usable Key Value To Identify. !!

```
<select   ng-options="ac.campaignId in campaigns | filter:{category: filterSelectOptions} | orderBy: 'name'" ng-model="S_SubStatusID">
<option selected="" value="-1">Activity</option>
</select>
```